# How do I join multiple tables to fetch the results based on a given criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been looking at this far too long and my brain feels like spaghetti noodles. Could someone help me out with a couple of queries?

*Tables*:

```
Presentation
------------
id          int 
name        varchar 
fk_template int     (references template.id)

Template
--------
id          int 
name        varchar 

Position
--------
id          int 
zorder      int     (if it is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd position of the given template)
fk_template int     (references Template.id)

Asset
-----
id          int 
name        varchar 
description varchar 

AssetForPresentation
--------------------
fk_asset        int  (references Asset.id)
fk_presentation int  (references Presentation.id)
fk_position     int  (references Position.id)
```

What I *think* I need to be asking at this point is basically "give me all of the assets AND their positions for this template."

You see, when a Presentation is brought it, it has a specific Template. Each Template has designated Positions, and each Position holds an Asset or NULL.

I need to be able to bring in all Assets and their individual positions for a particular Template used by a Presentation. **How would I query for something like that?**

I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: I'm asking how I would query for this... It's not only clearly laced throughout what I wrote, but the title of this question states simple "SQL: Selecting all assets AND their positions" ... as a curtesy, I always preface my titles with "SQL" if I'm looking for an "SQL" solution.

Comment: wasn't trying to be rude, it's just that everyone has limited time and with a long vague question it's just quicker for everyone to cut to the chase. If you say "I honestly don't even remember what I'm trying to query anymore" it's a bit of a warning sign. Glad that others were able to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the part you're having hard time with is two conditions on `JOIN` to the `AssetForPresentation` table.

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name,
  a.description
FROM Presentation AS p
JOIN Template AS t
  ON p.fk_template = t.id
LEFT JOIN Position AS pos
  ON pos.fk_template = t.id
LEFT JOIN AssetForPresentation AS afp
  ON afp.fk_presentation = p.id
  AND afp.fk_position = pos.id
LEFT JOIN Asset AS a
  ON a.id = afp.fk_asset
WHERE p.id = 123
ORDER BY pos.zorder ASC
```

Comment: Yes, I am most certainly having a hard time with that. I'm just so scrambled right now, I don't even know what I SHOULD be asking for... :/

Comment: The results are a bit much. And if I try to narrow for "*" to a few select fields, I get quite a bit of ambiguity.

Comment: What would you like to be included in the output?

Comment: Well, once this query is run, I'd like to be able to extract each position from an array (ORDER by zorder) and `echo` the contents out. So I don't think I'd need more than: Asset (id, name, etc), Position (zorder) ... and I looking at this correctly?

Comment: @dcolumbus You don't have to order in PHP, as it can be taken care of by sql's `ORDER BY`. See my updated answer, now it only includes the fields from `Asset`.

Comment: So you can reference "a" before you declare "a"? That's something I didn't know before. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @dcolumbus yes, that's one of the purposes of using aliases in the first place — to be able to refer the tables by those aliases in all places in the query.

Comment: @dcolumbus One more thing — if there's no asset, all the fields will contain `NULL`s instead. But if there are several `NULL` assets, wouldn't you need to know which one is which? Or just ordering by `zorder` is enough already?

Comment: Well, that's a good question. And from the `pos.zorder` I can see that in fact some positions are `NULL` while others are "filled" ... you see, I do have a physical representation of those positions within the template ... and when a Presentation is being saved, those positions are sent along as a hidden field.

Comment: @dcolumbus In case you have problems identifying `NULL` assets, you can just include `Position.id, Position.zorder` as result columns.

Comment: You've been an enormous help to me. Thanks so much! I wish I could contact you directly each time :)

Comment: @dcolumbus I'm glad I could help :) I'm afraid I'm not able to answer questions all the time, only when I feel like it, which is... sporadically :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have described in your question, you need to get all assets for a given template. I have created the table structure but didn't define the relation constraints on the table but used them while formulating the query.

You can join the `Asset` table to the `AssetForPresentation` table. Through AssetForPresentation table, you can join the `Presentation` and `Position` tables. The relation to the `Template` can be made through the `Position` table. Thus, joining the *Template* table to the *Asset* table to fetch all matching records.

You can view the demo in the below link.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a762/7)

Hope that helps.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE Presentation
(
        id          INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   name        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Template
(
        id          INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   name        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Position
(
        id          INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   zorder      INT         NOT NULL 
    ,   fk_template INT         NOT NULL 
    ,   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Asset
(
        id          INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   name        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE AssetForPresentation
(
        fk_asset        INT         NOT NULL
    ,   fk_presentation INT         NOT NULL
    ,   fk_position     INT         NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Presentation (name) VALUES
    ('presenation 1'),
    ('presenation 2');

INSERT INTO Template (name) VALUES
    ('template 1'),
    ('template 2');

INSERT INTO Position (zorder, fk_template) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2);

INSERT INTO Asset (name, description) VALUES
    ('asset 1', 'asset description 1'),
    ('asset 2', 'asset description 2');

INSERT INTO AssetForPresentation (fk_asset, fk_presentation, fk_position) 
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 2);

SELECT              *
FROM                Asset A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN    AssetForPresentation AP
ON                  A.id = AP.fk_asset
RIGHT OUTER JOIN    Presentation P
ON                  P.id = AP.fk_presentation
RIGHT OUTER JOIN    Position PO
ON                  PO.id = AP.fk_position
RIGHT OUTER JOIN    Template T
ON                  T.id = PO.fk_template
WHERE               T.id = 1;
```

*Output*:

```
ID NAME    DESCRIPTION         FK_ASSET FK_PRESENTATION FK_POSITION ZORDER FK_TEMPLATE
-- ------- ------------------- -------- --------------- ----------- ------ -----------
1  asset 1 asset description 1    1            1            1          1        1
1  asset 1 asset description 1    1            2            1          1        1
2  asset 2 asset description 2    2            2            1          1        1
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks for putting so much effort into your response. It's a huge help! I'll take a look through this and make sure I understand what you're doing here. Thank you again!

Comment: All the joins are `INNER JOIN`s, so your query assumes there's always an asset for each position. But if for some position there's no asset, this position will not show up in the result set. Which seems to not fit into OP's requirement.

Comment: Well, in the end, I'd love to be able to present this to the view as an Array. As long as I can loop over the array, and if a position is `empty()` or `NULL`, that should be fine... that record just won't be created in the `AssetForPresentation` table upon `save()` ... Does that seem logical?

Comment: @Siva, I believe it is. I just wanted to make sure I said ^ that in case you two had any worries about my potential use of such a query.

Comment: @dcolumbus If using `INNER JOIN` like in Siva's answer, there will be no `NULL`s for the asset. You won't even know there's such a position, because it will not be included in the result. To have it included as a `NULL`'ed record, you have to use `LEFT JOIN`, like in my answer.

Comment: @Shedal, yes I see what you mean ... and it is quite valuable knowing that a position is NOT filled.

Comment: @Siva actually, as in your answer order of tables is reversed, compared to mine, you need `RIGHT JOIN`s instead of left ones. Sorry for my previous misleading comment.